# How to handle SPA when following Modular approach?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I am using this: https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules to split my app into modules and https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-vue to apply ( server driven SPA ).

And I have modules like:

```
 - Front ( front-site )
 - Admin ( admin-dashboard)
 - Post
 - User
 - Tag
```

I want my app/public folder to be something like this:

```
- js/front/app.js
- js/admin/app.js
```

Module/Front/Resources/Views/app.blade.php

```
<body>

<div id="app" data-page="{{ json_encode($page) }}"></div>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/front/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

Module/Admin/Resources/Views/app.blade.php

```
<body>

<div id="app" data-page="{{ json_encode($page) }}"></div>

<script src="{{ mix('/js/admin/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
```

I am having a hard time to understand how to connect all modules's Vue components together.

- Where should I put User, Tag and Post modules's Vue components? inside the module? or in App/resources/js?
- There are 2 views are the entry-point to my app ( Front - Admin ), how to connect other Vue component to them ?

Comment: You should use controllers and routes based on which views from js folder can be rendered. Front will be your root directory, and front/admin route can render admin view.